# Opposite of IN operator in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

How could I do the opposite of:

[image: example]

In other words select all the people whose last name is NOT Hansen or Pettersen.

Comment: (Keep reading the tutorial/reference that image came from? ^^)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
WHERE lastname NOT IN ('Hansen', 'Pettersen')
```

see the section "The IN and NOT IN operators" in [SQL As Understood By SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

Comment: Could it really be that simple?  Yes it could!

Comment: I'm both saddened and amused at how much rep gets distributed on these ridiculous questions (I've  taken my share too).  I think if people weren't too lazy to read search results half the people with 5k+ rep would be under 1000.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE LastName NOT IN ('Hansen','Pettersen')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can negate the `IN` with `NOT`:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons
WHERE LastName NOT IN ('hansen', 'Pettersen')
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons
Where LastName NOT IN (...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Negate your condition with NOT.

```
select * from persons
where NOT (LastName IN ('Hansen','Pettersen'));
```

Comment: That's kind of a bad coding style.

Comment: I have to say this is the first time I have seen this kind of code. If I didn't read the question. This would totally confuse the hell out of me