# What is the opposite of the in function at mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

with in function I can found the row with specified values:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE value IN (1,3,4);
```

but How could I select the values that isn't  1,3,4:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE value != (1,3,4);
```

Comment: out - no, NOT IN

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opposite of IN operator in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219526/opposite-of-in-operator-in-sql)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE value NOT IN (1,3,4);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE value IS NULL OR value NOT IN (1,3,4)
 ;
```

Explanation:

- IN  removes duplicates and NULLs: `(a,b,b, NULL)` --> `(a,b)`
- Comparing NULL to a value yields `false`
- Comparing NULL to NULL also yields `false`

As a result:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE color IN ('red', 'blue');
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE color NOT IN ('red', 'blue');
```

Need not count up to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable;
```